# Fixing a broken link: website/terms without .html

Tags: html, url-rewriting

I recently hardcoded into an app `www.website/Terms` instead of `website/Terms.html`. Now when you click the link in the app, it gives the following error:

> File 404 Error Not Found

How can I fix this (without altering the app).

Comment: You could set up a rewrite rule.

Comment: Hmm can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache? IIS? Edit your question to include the tag [rewrite] and [apache] or [iis] or whatever web server you're using.

Comment: I'm using Godaddy website builder. Sorry I am not an html programmer, instead objective c.

Comment: I have the issue with /Terms and /Privacy

Comment: I was just passing by, but I've added the [rewrite] tag for you. The good folks in the [rewrite] group can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the app, then you'll need to edit the `.htaccess` file with a simple redirect:

```
Redirect 301 Terms Terms.html
```

Or a more complicated rewrite (though in this situation, I can't imagine you would need the power of rewrites, which is catered towards a more powerful set of conditions).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule Terms Terms.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @bobymcgookers If you log into your hosting management, and go to the highest-level directory, you should be able to see `.htaccess` and edit it yourself.

Comment: And do you mean "if you CAN'T change the app"

Comment: @bobymcgookers Ah yes, sorry, I meant if you can't change it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking under Domain Details, where I see three sections, Settings, DNS zone file, and Contacts...

Comment: @bobymcgookers Oops - I meant your hosting. Presumably you own the hosting for the site? You'll need to access those files through GoDaddy's interface in Cpanel.

Comment: OOh subdomain forwarding!

Comment: For those of you reading this, Goddady has a built in "subdomain" redirect feature that alters the .htaccess file in the way that Singulat1ty described.

Comment: Hmm actually subdomain forwarding is more like privacy.website.com, not what I was looking for. but I will try to use the above strategies.